# how to make mysql query using dynamic array

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, node.js

i have two array as follows

```
var fieldarray =  [ 'category',
                    'bookid',
                    'bookauthor',
                    'booktitle',
                    'price',
                    'publication',
                    'publication_date' ]

var dataarray =  [ 'fantasy',
                    '',
                    'JKR',
                     '',
                     '',
                     '',
                     '' ]
```

every time **count of elements** in fieldarray and dataarray will be same , but elements will be different, in data array some elements can be empty,

i have to use these array in a mysql statement.My expected mysql query is as follows

```
select category,bookid,bookauthor,booktitle,price,publication,publication_date from tbl_books where category like '%fantasy%' OR bookauthor like '%JKR%'
```

how can i make mysql statements dynamically based on fiedarray and dataarray elements in nodejs

Comment: You should definetly use a mysql module that allows for querying...

Answer (score 0):

```
 var filters = [];

 dataarray.forEach((val, index) => {
   if(val)
    filters.push(`${fieldarray[index]} like '%${val}%'`);
 });

var result = `select ${fieldarray.join(",")} from tbl_books where ${filters.join(" OR ")} `;
```

Just iterate over your dataarray, check if the field is not empty and concat it to the resulting query. Always make shure that you are not affected by SQL injections!

Comment: This answer is susceptible to SQL injection.

Comment: Such as this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sql-template-strings. That'll not work for identifiers, though.

Comment: @Ilja OP should definetly escape both arrays before.

Comment: Or simply not escape manually, but use placeholders, except in case of col and table names. Whitelisting's one good approach to that.

Answer (score 0):

Prepare a map first linking field with data using reduce

```
var map = fieldarray.reduce( ( a, c, i ) => ( dataarray[i] && (a[c] = dataarray[i]), a ) , {}) ;
```

Now prepare the query dynamically using `join` and `map`

```
var query = "SELECT " + fieldarray.join(" , ") + "from tbl_books where " + Object.keys(map).map(f => (f + " like '%" + map[f] + "%'")).join(" AND ");
```

**Demo**

```js
var fieldarray = ['category',
  'bookid',
  'bookauthor',
  'booktitle',
  'price',
  'publication',
  'publication_date'
]

var dataarray = ['fantasy',
  '',
  'JKR',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  ''
];
var map = fieldarray.reduce((a, c, i) => (dataarray[i] && (a[c] = dataarray[i]), a), {});

var query = "SELECT " + fieldarray.join(" , ") + "from tbl_books where " + Object.keys(map).map(f => (f + " like '%" + map[f] + "%'")).join(" AND ");

console.log(query);
```

To avoid sql-injection pass the values as params instead of hard-coding them in the query using [mysqljs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values)

```
var query = "SELECT " + fieldarray.join(" , ") + "from tbl_books where " + Object.keys(map).map(f => (f + " like ?")).join(" AND ");

connection.query( query, Object.values(map), function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  // ...
});
```

Comment: This too is open for SQL injection.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Yes, shared an alternative to hard-coding the values.

Comment: @JonasW. SparseArray ? Didn't get you.

Comment: And this is still open to sql injection vie the parameters :/

Comment: @JonasW. It is a parameterized query now. Can you elaborate on how this is open to sql-injection?

Comment: Usually you don't quote around placeholders, and that may actually defeat the purpose of a placeholder, depending on the library in use. `'?'` when replaced may result in `'' OR 1 = 1 -- ''`, for example.

Comment: `fieldarray = ["* FROM nothing; DROP TABLE tbl_books; SELECT * FROM nothing"]`

Comment: @JonasW. *map is an array. With key values -> u g l y!*  Not sure how it being ugly is relevant, but map is not an array!

Comment: @IljaEverilä Yeah, didn't noticed that.. I have removed the quotes. With quotes, it wouldn't have worked anyways.

Comment: @JonasW. It wasn't meant to be.. In the demo I had shared, it wasn't a map. Otherwise why would I do `Object.keys(map)` instead of simply `map.map`? In any case, how does it being ugly or not-ugly becomes relevant to the OP's question?